# Working with Excel ? In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, i write the code for displaying the data in excel sheet to gridview. it is working fine but, can i track the sheet name of that particular excel sheet. For example i have sample.xls in that how can i find the sheet name. i write the query like this

```
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oledbConn);
```

How can i find the sheet name of the particular excel and if the excel sheet having more than one sheet then how can i display the data. can you help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use [OleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable.aspx) Method.

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new 
               OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        DataTable schemaTable = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(
            OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,
            new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
        return schemaTable;
    }
```